# Why in VB.NET is not possible te declare a NotOverridable method?

Tags: vb.net, inheritance

I'm trying to avoid that sub-classes of my class can override my method.

If I try to do so by using the `NotOverridable` keyword:

```
Public Class Class1
    Protected NotOverridable Sub DoSomething()
    End Sub
End Class
```

I get this error:

```
'NotOverridable' cannot be specified on methods that do not override another method
```

Comment: `NotOverridable` is `sealed`. If there is nothing to seal, there's no point in sealing. You declare a non-overridable method by not declaring it `Overridable`. `Protected Sub DoSomething()` is non-overridable.

Comment: I tried that, but in the sub-class it's possible to override the method:
`Public Class Class2
    Inherits Class1

    Protected Overloads Sub DoSomething()
    End Sub
End Class`

Comment: No, it is not possible. What you are almost certainly doing is shadowing the method. In order to override you actually have to use the `Overrides` keyword.

Comment: Overloading is not overriding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that you have this class:

```vb
Public Class GrandParent

    Protected Sub Method1()

    End Sub

    Protected Overridable Sub Method2()

    End Sub

End Class
```

and then you have this class:

```vb
Public Class Parent
    Inherits GrandParent

    Protected Sub Method1()

    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub Method2()

    End Sub

End Class
```

`Parent.Method2` is overriding `GrandParent.Method2`, just as indicated. On the other hand, `Parent.Method1` is NOT overriding `GrandParent.Method1`. That code generates the following warning:

> sub 'Method1' shadows an overloadable member declared in the base
>   class 'GrandParent'.  If you want to overload the base method, this
>   method must be declared 'Overloads'.

If you change the code to the following:

```vb
Public Class Parent
    Inherits GrandParent

    Protected Overrides Sub Method1()

    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub Method2()

    End Sub

End Class
```

then you get the following error:

> 'Protected Overrides Sub Method1()' cannot override 'Protected Sub
>   Method1()' because it is not declared 'Overridable'.

Shadowing is different to overloading in that shadowing honours the type of the reference while overriding honours the type of the object. That means that, if you you have a `Parent` object assigned to a `GrandParent` variable, calling `Method1` will invoke `GrandParent.Method1` based on the type of the reference and calling `Method2` will invoke `Parent.Method2` based on the type of the object. Overriding implements polymorphism where shadowing does not. The first implementation of `Parent` is equivalent to this:

```vb
Public Class Parent
    Inherits GrandParent

    Protected Shadows Sub Method1()

    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub Method2()

    End Sub

End Class
```

If you were to then add this class:

```vb
Public Class Child
    Inherits Parent

    Protected Overrides Sub Method2()

    End Sub

End Class
```

it would work as expected. If you changed the `Parent` class to this:

```vb
Public Class Parent
    Inherits GrandParent

    Protected Shadows Sub Method1()

    End Sub

    Protected NotOverridable Overrides Sub Method2()

    End Sub

End Class
```

then that `Child implementation would generate this error:

> 'Protected Overrides Sub Method2()' cannot override 'Protected
>   NotOverridable Overrides Sub Method2()' because it is declared
>   'NotOverridable'.

That is the only reason to use the `NotOverridable` keyword, i.e. to prevent derived classes overriding your own overridden implementation of an inherited member.

Comment: @Couper Yes you can.

Comment: @GSerg I don't have enough reputation.